# How can I use "docker run -v" without letting the container delete the mapped contents?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

```
$ docker run -it -v $PWD/path/to/data:/data myimg:latest
```

I understand that the `-v` option is the way of mapping an external folder into the container.

However, using this allows the container to delete the data on the host, when I only intend to provide read access. How can this be constrained?

Comment: That's only a security hole if someone documented a security *constraint* that it violates. Containers are very explicitly documented to behave exactly the way you describe here, so no constraint is broken.

Comment: Which is to say -- you've got a valid question, but the title as initially written is making a somewhat inflammatory assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation is correct; a container that is given access to a volume with -v would have access to the files in it. By default that access is read/write and the instance could remove data files.

Best practice is don't give access to a container that it doesn't need. So if a container doesn't need access to a volume to persist or share data with other containers simply don't map the volume.

If the container does need the data but doesn't need to write it you can [mount the volume as read only](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume):

```
$ docker run -d \
   --name=nginxtest \
   -v nginx-vol:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
   nginx:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way a security "hole" (aka unintentional side effect impacting security). It is intended behaviour, though bind-mounting is discouraged. And it does not impact security at all. An *"unintentional"* recursive and forced delete? You could do this on the host machine as well.

I get the impression that you mix the concept of virtual machines and containers. A virtual machine is an isolated OS running on a host. A container is (ideally) an isolated process, which might or might not have access to some rather limited  parts of the host's filesystem. It would not be too far from the truth when you think of containers as a software package which brings it's dependencies and (mostly) predefined configuration and the package manager is able to limit the ressources used by said process.